# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY] error while creating a android app using rhomobile and jquerymobile

Tags: android, rhomobile

Emulator is up and running
Loading package

```
PWD: D:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.0.5/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-3.3.3
CMD: F:/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -e install -r D:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.0.5/Workspace/test/bin/target/android/test-debug.apk
pkg: /data/local/tmp/test-debug.apk

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]

67 KB/s (12429119 bytes in 180.288s)
Failed to load (possibly because emulator not done launching)- retrying
PWD: D:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.0.5/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rhodes-3.3.3
CMD: F:/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -e install -r D:/MotorolaRhoMobileSuite2.0.5/Workspace/test/bin/target/android/test-debug.apk
pkg: /data/local/tmp/test-debug.apk

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [RhoMobile for Android](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhoconnect/client-java) documentation, it requires a native library called `librhoconnectclient.so`. I expect when you created your app it didn't have the native library placed in the right directory and the deploy fails because it can't find it. Look at your setup to verify you have everything correctly installed.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input